# setuptools adds 150ms startup latency to all scripts

Tags: python, setuptools, packaging

I'm working on a cross-platform Python project. It's a command-line tool with shell autocompletion, so speed matters.

The way `setuptools` generates the console script is imposing at least 150ms overhead - sometimes more. This is simply unacceptable for the kind of tool I'm writing, and shouldn't be necessary given how little it does in the basic case.

I'm trying to follow best practice for a modern Python project, so I'm using `setuptools` to build the project. The package supports windows, so its ability to generate binary wrappers for entry points is essential.

This happens regardless of how I install the package - `pip install`, `pip install -e`, `pip install --egg`, `python setup.py install`, etc.

There's a [github issue](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/510) discussing the problem, but no workaround or solution so far.

Elsewhere I've seen people moving back to distutils because of this, but that's not an option for my project.

The only workaround I can think of is somehow extending or customising what `setuptools` does when it installs by project so that the binary shim doesn't use `pkg_resources`.

What can I do short of that fairly drastic and unconstructive measure?

---

My `setup.py` is basic - roughly as follows:

```
import pip.req
import setuptools

def install_reqs():
    reqs = pip.req.parse_requirements('requirements.txt', session=False)
    reqs = [str(ir.req) for ir in reqs]
    return reqs

setuptools.setup(
    name='myproj',
    version='v1.0.0-dev',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(exclude=('tests')),
    install_requires=install_reqs(),
    include_package_data=True,
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'myproj = myproj.cli.myproj:main',
        ]
    },
)
```

The shim that setuptools generates for the entrypoint looks like this:

```
!$myhome/.venv/myproj/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'myproj==1.0.0.dev0','console_scripts','myproj'
__requires__ = 'myproj==1.0.0.dev0'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('myproj==1.0.0.dev0', 'console_scripts', 'myproj')()
    )
```

Here are some `cProfile` stats using the setuptools-generated console script:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
121/1    0.015    0.000    0.278    0.278 {built-in method builtins.exec}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.278    0.278 myproj:3(<module>)
125/3    0.001    0.000    0.221    0.074 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:966(_find_and_load)
125/3    0.001    0.000    0.221    0.074 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:939(_find_and_load_unlocked)
125/5    0.001    0.000    0.219    0.044 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:659(_load_unlocked)
 99/5    0.001    0.000    0.219    0.044 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:656(exec_module)
152/4    0.000    0.000    0.218    0.054 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:214(_call_with_frames_removed)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.204    0.102 __init__.py:15(<module>)
32/15    0.000    0.000    0.135    0.009 {built-in method builtins.__import__}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.088    0.088 __init__.py:540(load_entry_point)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.085    0.085 __init__.py:2564(load_entry_point)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.083    0.083 __init__.py:2216(load)
```

And here it is as a custom script without the setuptools shim:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 58/1    0.006    0.000    0.053    0.053 {built-in method builtins.exec}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.053    0.053 test.py:1(<module>)
 53/3    0.000    0.000    0.052    0.017 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:966(_find_and_load)
 53/3    0.000    0.000    0.052    0.017 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:939(_find_and_load_unlocked)
 53/5    0.000    0.000    0.051    0.010 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:659(_load_unlocked)
 65/4    0.000    0.000    0.051    0.013 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:214(_call_with_frames_removed)
 45/5    0.000    0.000    0.051    0.010 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:656(exec_module)
```

The custom script - test.py - is very simple:

```
from myproj.cli.myproj import main

main()
```

Comment: So then write your own script.

Comment: How would I deploy it? When setuptools deploys something from either `console_scripts` or `scripts`, it generates the shim that uses `load_entry_point()`, which is slow.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue too if I install a project from source using 'pip install .'.  However if I build a binary wheel file first and then install the wheel,  the generated shim does not appear to use pkg_resources and is faster.  I've tested this with the cookiecutter project:

https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter

If I clone this project and then install using the original method, 'pip install .', the generated executable script contains the import from pkg_resources (and is slow):

```
#!/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'cookiecutter==1.5.1','console_scripts','cookiecutter'
__requires__ = 'cookiecutter==1.5.1'
import re
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('cookiecutter==1.5.1', 'console_scripts', 'cookiecutter')()
    )
```

However if I do the following two commands:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
pip install dist/cookiecutter-1.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

the generated shim does not contain pkg_resources (and is faster):

```
#!/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from cookiecutter.__main__ import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

And when I tried the latter method on Windows, it still created the .exe shim.